# Look up specific string in row (not column) and return value of cell x columns left of that location

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

My data looks like this:

**Sheet 1:**

```
A B C D E F
1 2 3 a b c 
1 2 3 a b c 
1 2 3 a b c
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
A B
a
b
c
```

Now on Sheet 2 in Column B I would like to return the result of: look up each value of Column A in Sheet 2 in Columns C-D in Sheet 1 and return the content of the cell 3 cells left of that location. So that in Sheet 2, Column B I would get: 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I realised this is very easy to do with the LOOKUP() function. In Sheet 2 Cell B1 I would put: =LOOKUP(A1,'Sheet 1'!D1:F1,'Sheet 1'!A1:C1)